# Create a new column whose formula depends on a cell value of another row

Tags: r

How do I create a new column whose formula depends on a cell value of another row

```
  x y  z
1 a 1 10
2 a 2 20
3 a 3 30
4 b 1 40
```

This is my sample data. I want the final output to be as follows

```
  x y  z prevY
1 a 1 10 0
2 a 2 20 10
3 a 3 30 20
4 b 1 40 0
```

where prevY is the z value for x=current_x_val and y=current_y_val-1 0 if not available.

How do I achieve this.

My progress so far :

```
data[data$x == "a" & data$y==2-1,3]
```

I manually enter the values and get the prevY for each row. but how do i do it for all rows in a single shot ?

Answer (score 2):

Here you can use the `ave()` function for doing group level transformations (here, a different transformation for each value of x).

```
dd$prevY <- with(dd, ave(z, x, FUN=function(x) head(c(0,x),-1)))
```

Here we take the values of z for each value of x and add a zero on the front and remove the last value. Then we assign this back to the data.frame.

This assumes that all the `y` values are sorted within each `x` group.

The result is

```
  x y  z prevY
1 a 1 10     0
2 a 2 20    10
3 a 3 30    20
4 b 1 40     0
```

Comment: Yep, that's the go, though I prefer: `c(0,head(x,-1))` in the function.

Comment: what is the reason for using with ? 
    ave(z, x, FUN=function(x)c(0,x[-length(x)])))
seems to get the result for me.

Comment: @user2070649 Did you attach your data.frame by chance? I was just assuming x,y and z only lived inside your data.frame which i called `dd` here. If you have them as global variables, you don't need the `with`.

Comment: @thelatemail I always go back and forth on those two syntaxes. But i think in this case your suggestion is cleaner so I changed it.

Answer (score 2):

Or `data.table` solution (similar to MrFlick) but faster for a big data set

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, prevY := c(0, z[-length(z)]), by = x]
```